# Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, drag-and-drop

I am hitting the following error when attempting to drag items from one UICollectionView (collectionView) into another (rackView):

'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (7) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (6), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

The strange thing is, almost the exact same code works for dragging and dropping when I am dragging the items from rackView into collectionView. rackView updates correctly when items are deleted from rack datasource but crashes when items are added back into it from the board (collectionView). Does anyone know why this is happening and is there any way to solve it?

Thanks for any information you can provide.

I've tried to add a variable which represents the count that's in the rack and return that in the numberOfItemsInSection method. This is stated as a possible solution for this error elsewhere but doesn't seem to resolve it for me.

```
private func moveItemsFromRack(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView)
{
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

        for (index, item) in coordinator.items.enumerated()
        {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: destinationIndexPath.row + index, section: destinationIndexPath.section)

            self.board[indexPath.row] = item.dragItem.localObject as! String
            self.rack.remove(at: self.sourceIndex.row)

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [destinationIndexPath])
            self.rackView.reloadData()
        }

    })

    self.sourceIndex = []

}

private func moveItemsFromBoard(coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator, destinationIndexPath: IndexPath, collectionView: UICollectionView)
{

    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

        for (index, item) in coordinator.items.enumerated()
        {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: destinationIndexPath.row + index, section: destinationIndexPath.section)
            self.rack.insert(item.dragItem.localObject as! String, at: indexPath.row)
            self.board[self.sourceIndex.row] = ""
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [self.sourceIndex])
            self.rackView.reloadData()
        }
    })
    self.sourceIndex = []
}
```

Comment: You can use diffing algorithm. Please check the following link: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/a-better-way-to-update-uicollectionview-data-in-swift-with-diff-framework-924db158db86

Comment: Thanks for this Victor, I'll look into implementing this today.

Answer (score 1):

I actually just removed the performBatchUpdates method and this issue was resolved.
An explanation for why is here:
https://fangpenlin.com/posts/2016/04/29/uicollectionview-invalid-number-of-items-crash-issue/